# Function Value with Combination(or Permutation) of Variables and Assign to Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have `n` variables. Suppose `n` equals 3 in this case. I want to apply one function to all of the combinations(or permutations, depending on how you want to solve this) of variables and store the result in the same row and column in dataframe.

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
indexes = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df = pd.DataFrame({x:np.nan for x in indexes}, index=indexes)
```

If I apply sum(the function can be anything), then the result that I want to get is like this:

```
    a   b   c
a   2   3   4
b   3   4   5
c   4   5   6
```

I can only think of iterating all the variables, apply the function one by one, and use the index of the iterators to set the value in the dataframe. Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use apply and return a `pd.Series` for that effect. In such cases, `pandas` uses the series indices as columns in the resulting dataframe.

```
s = pd.Series({"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3})
s.apply(lambda x: x+s)
```

Just note that the operation you do is between an element and a series.

Comment: If the variables' values are iterable and the function will produce one value from 2 of these variables, how can I achieve the result that I need?

Comment: ```a,b,c = (1,2), (2,3), (3,4)``` and the function is scipy stats' Pearson Correlation

Comment: Is it not better the export to to a `DataFrame` with columns `["a","b","c"]`, and then run `df.corr()`? In general, direct vector calculations are faster then `apply`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need broadcast sum of array created from variables if performance is important:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
indexes = ['a', 'b', 'c']

arr = np.array([a,b,c])
df =  pd.DataFrame(arr + arr[:, None], index=indexes, columns=indexes)
print (df)
   a  b  c
a  2  3  4
b  3  4  5
c  4  5  6
```

Comment: If the variables' values are iterable and the function will produce one value from 2 of these variables, how can I achieve the result that I need?